# Can't install git related packages on Ubuntu 18.04 due to unmet dependency

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, git

When trying to install gitk via 
`sudo apt install gitk`
i get the output

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gitk : Depends: git (< 1:2.17.1-.)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i have tried installing an older version of git with the command

```
sudo apt install git=1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1
```

which produces the output

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.0-.) but 1:2.18.0-0ppa1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't understand why it says that 2.18 is to be installed when i specified an older version to be installed in the command.
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and my git is currently version 2.18.0.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a PPA?  Because it looks like you have a version mismatch between Git in the repositories and Git in a PPA, hence the mismatch problems.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks, that was it. I apparently had a ppa from a different ubuntu version, after removing "git-core-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list" from my /etc/apt/sources.list.d and running "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa" as well as "sudo apt upgrade" everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a PPA that also provides `git`.  This is resulting in the version confusion that you're seeing that prevents installations.

Per your comment, you removed `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` and then ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`.  Once that happened, your `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` worked.

Comment: Can you explain this answer, so that it might be more useful to someone else who has the same problem? For example, how to determine which file needs deleting?

Comment: @TimRandall It'll be different for each case - in this case the user solved the issue themselves so I simply posted that at the time so OP could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** The `git-core` source withing your `sources.list.d` doesn't match your Ubuntu release.

**Solution:**

1. Find out what is your release name from this [list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)
2. Find the conflictive ppa (a `git-core` ppa that doesn't match your release name).

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d | grep git-core
```

3. Remove the conflictive ppa

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-<wrong_release_name>.list`
```

4. Reinstall the right ppa for git-core

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

5. Update and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```